# Unreal Engine 4 : Load OBJ file

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am try to load an OBJ file in my C++ script but it is everytime NULL. Why?

```
UStaticMesh* mesh = Cast<UStaticMesh>(StaticLoadObject(UStaticMesh::StaticClass(), NULL, TEXT("StaticMesh'/Game/StarterContent/Materials/Frame_02392'")));

if(mesh == NULL)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Empty Mesh!"));
}
```

Comment: You can use createMeshSection node.

Answer (score 0):

A static mesh object and a `.OBJ` file are not the same thing.

The former is a file containing a UE4-specific asset and the latter is a mesh interchange file (often with an associated `.MTL` material file).

The `.OBJ` files needs to be imported by the Unreal Editor in order to create the asset file, which can then be added to the scene, dynamically or otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to load an OBJ+MTL+PNG 'thing' by code?

Comment: @user2011909 No, I don't believe so, not without adding lots of code to the runtime, which is currently in the editor.  It might be trivial, but it's not a normal thing to do.

Comment: Or to script the import and converting (obj -> asset) work flow in C++?

Comment: @user2011909 That's what you'd have to do, yes.  How much work is involved is unknown to me.